Is there a proper way to log chat interactions for azure prompt flow?
We're currently looking for a way to track how our chatbot is used and therefore want to track the user input. Currently, at least as far as I'm concerned, there's no way to check previous inputs by default. Did you connect an external logging application, is there some way to do this cleanly with azure tools?
I used Azure Prompt Flow via Azure Machine Learning Studio. I can only see Deployment and ARM logs but no User interaction logs by default. How can I log chat interactions?

Promptflow Tracing is what you want.
pip install promptflow-tracing and then use it with start_trace() or @trace decorator on your functions.
Then in ML Studio, there is a new Tracing tab under Prompt flow where you can see node inputs and outputs.
If you can't see it, you may have to turn Observe your LLM application with Trace  on in Manage preview features (top right) as it's still in preview.
Alternatively, you can hook up your own OTEL collector and get the logs out that way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter-readme?view=azure-python-preview
